# Replace certain woocommerce product names with an image

Tags: hook-woocommerce

I'm using this script for add an image near product name title in woocommerce, but i need to edit only some product ids:

```
  remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_template_single_title', 5);
    function custom_template_single_title() {
        global $product;
        echo '<h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">'
             . '<img src="your_image.jpg">' 
             . $product->get_title() 
             . '</h1>';
    }
```

I would like to be able to insert an image instead of the product title, but only for some products of my choice